# Quartz Cron Trigger which fires a job for every 40 seconds

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I faced a weird situation, where I have an only option to use Cron trigger and need to trigger a job for every 40 seconds. Is this possible with Cron trigger. If yes, can you please help.

My expression could go like below:

0/40 * * * * ?

actual result:

- job executed at 12:00:00
- job executed at 12:00:40
- job executed at 12:01:00
- job executed at 12:01:40

expected result:

- job executed at 12:00:00
- job executed at 12:00:40
- job executed at 12:01:20
- job executed at 12:02:00

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you see any parse error, miss fire, etc. exceptions/errors in `quartz.log`

Comment: @sozkul no not getting any exception/error, but don't see the job is trigerred at desired or expected time.

Comment: sometimes, database of quartz is not updated as expected, check trigger definitions . is there any difference ?

Comment: Yes it is perfect. @sozkul even the documentation says the trigger's behavior is as resulted. I feel, the expression doesn't meet the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

in quartz configuration xml file, set `<cron-expression>` of job definition like below;

```
<cron-expression>0/40 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
```

Also, keep in mind that every 40 seconds works like;

```
fire on 10:00:40
fire on 10:01:20
fire on 10:02:00
...
```

Comment: the above expression is not working as expected. it triggers a job at 40th second of every minute.  i.e. at 10:00:40, 10:01:40 & 10:02:40 and so on..

Comment: thanks for the time & response. Now we are allowing user select his own trigger(simple/cron) as per his/her requirement. Thanks again.